# Django-TinyMCE Validation Rules

Tags: django, django-models, tinymce, django-admin, django-tinymce

I am using TinyMCE in my Django Admin site. I need to validate that no disallowed HTML Tags get submitted. This is what I tried:

1) Validation Method

```
    def check_for_invalid_html_tags(value) :
        compiled_regex = re.compile('<(?!/?(p|div|ul|li)(>|\s))[^<]+?>')

        if compiled_regex.match(value):
            raise ValidationError('Invalid Tags')
```

2) Validation Rule

```
    content = tinymce_models.HTMLField(validators=[check_for_invalid_html_tags])
```

This does not seem to work, as any submission is let through as valid. When I change the tinymce_models.HTMLField to models.TextField, the rule works perfectly. Thus I believe that the issue is as a result of TinyMCE.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I read the doc and there is a slight difference between `match` and `search`

match:

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string ...

search:

> Scan through string looking for the first location ...

[search() vs. match()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

since what your are looking for might be everywhere in your string you need to use `search` instead of `match`. An other point, you might neeed to set the fag re.S or re.DOTALL since you might have newline in your input.

> Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline.

So here is the check_for_invalid_html_tags in a functor and a working solution.

```
import re

class CheckForInvalidHtmlTags(object):
    compiled_regex = re.compile('<(?!/?(p|div|ul|li)(>|\s))[^<]+?>')

    def __call__(self, value):
        if self.compiled_regex.search(value):
            print 'error'
        else:
            print 'ok'

c = CheckForInvalidHtmlTags()
c('test test <a>test<a> test') # print error
c('test <p> test</p>') # print ok
c('test<a> test</a><p>test</p>test') # print error
```

Comment: to use it in do that `content = tinymce_models.HTMLField(validators=[CheckForInvalidHtmlTags()])`

Comment: the solution use a functor but a simple function is fine too

Comment: Great. The issue was using match and not search. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your validation method must actually be a validator, which has special methods like __call__. Use one of django's core validators, like the regex validator.

```
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

check_for_invalid_html_tags = RegexValidator(
        regex=''<(?!/?(p|div|ul|li)(>|\s))[^<]+?>'',
        message='Invalid Tags',
        code='invalid_content'
    )
```

Then in your model:

```
content = tinymce_models.HTMLField(validators=[check_for_invalid_html_tags])
```

Comment: Thank you Jamie. I tried this and it does not seem to work. This causes any submission to fail validation. For example: If I try <tr>Test</tr>, it fails. <p>Test</p> also fails and so does Test. From these 3 examples I would expect only the 1st one to fail as the HTML Tag is not allowed

Comment: What the validator needs is a callable object so either a simple function or a functor: A functor is an object which redefine the \_\_call__ method. I think in that case the functor can be 'better' since the regex should be compile one time.

Comment: MoiTux, you're right, but compiling a regex has a negligible affect on performance, especially for this use case. The validator also has other functions that are convenient for the developer, including __init__ and __eq__. Rewriting these is unreasonable in this case.